# Unable to combine videos with ffmpeg on firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions

I tried to combine videos on firebase functions using FFmpeg. However, I was not able to do that because of encountering an error below.

I expect that videos will be combined successfully.

Firstly, as I did not have the directory made so I tried to make it using `mkdirp-promise`.
But it did not make any changes; I had the same error as before.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/tmp/combined.mp4'
```

Here are the codes.

```
const combineVideos = async (tempFilePath, firstFilePath, secondFilePath,targetTempFilePath) =>{
                ffmpeg(tempFilePath)
                  .setFfmpegPath(ffmpeg_static.path)
                  .addInput(firstFilePath)
                  .addInput(secondFilePath)
                  .on('end', function() {
                    console.log('files have been merged succesfully');
                  })
                  .on('error', function(err) {
                    console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
                  })
                  .mergeToFile(targetTempFilePath)
}
```

```
exports.editVids = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    await (async () => {
        const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
        const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.

        // Get the file name.
        const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
        // Exit if the audio is already converted.
        if(fileName==='last.mp4'){
            // Download file from bucket.

            const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
            const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
            const firstFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'first.mp4');
            const secondFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'second.mp4');

            // We add a '_output.flac' suffix to target audio file name. That's where we'll upload the converted audio.
            const targetTempFileName = 'combined.mp4'
            const targetTempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), targetTempFileName);
            const targetStorageFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), targetTempFileName);

            await mkdirp(path.dirname(tempFilePath))

            await bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath});
            await bucket.file(filePath.replace('last.mp4','first.mp4')).download({destination: firstFilePath});
            await bucket.file(filePath.replace('last.mp4','second.mp4')).download({destination: secondFilePath});

            console.log('Video downloaded locally to', firstFilePath);
            console.log('Video downloaded locally to', secondFilePath);
            console.log('Video downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
            // Convert the audio to mono channel using FFMPEG.
            await combineVideos(tempFilePath, firstFilePath, secondFilePath, targetTempFilePath)
            console.log('Output video created at', targetTempFilePath);

            // Uploading the audio.
            await bucket.upload(targetTempFilePath, {destination: targetStorageFilePath});
            console.log('Output video uploaded to', targetStorageFilePath);

            // Once the audio has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
            fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
            fs.unlinkSync(firstFilePath);
            fs.unlinkSync(secondFilePath);
            fs.unlinkSync(targetTempFilePath);
            return console.log('Temporary files removed.', targetTempFilePath);
        }
    })();
});
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why you want to mkdirp on an output file.  mkdirp makes directories, not files.  /tmp already exists in Cloud Functions, so there's no need to write any code to create it.  You can just start writing the file whenever you want.

Comment: Yeah I think so too but I saw codes that use ffmpeg and work fine on Firebase cloud functions written that way so I thought I should’ve written so whereas I didn’t find it quite effective.